# joining two files based on first column IDs

Tags: ubuntu, join, awk, grep

I have two files, with the pattern

file1 (smaller file)

```
001 word1
002 word2
... ....
00n wordn
```

file2 (bigger file)

```
001 word3
002 word4
... ....
00n wordn
```

I want to get an output file that keeps only matching lines from both files, based on the first column of file1 and joins the two lines where it finds a common column ID, such as, for example

```
001 001 word1 word 3
```

Tried various comobos of join, grep and awk but the task seems to be beyond me.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encourage on SO, thankyou.

Comment: Wouldn't "002 002 word2 word4" be in the resulting output as well?

Comment: Yes, all lines that match the first column in file 1 and are also present in file2 should be in the output

Comment: Have you considered the `comm` command?

Comment: What did not work in your `join`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file1
001 word1
002 word2
00n wordn1

$ cat file2 
001 word3
002 word4
003 word_u1
004 word_u2
00n wordn2
```

(Note the extra `003 word_u1` and `004 word_u2` in file2...)

You can use `join` that joins those files (as presented) together:

```
$ join file1 file2
001 word1 word3
002 word2 word4
00n wordn1 wordn2
```

If the files are not sorted (as you have presented them) you can sort first:

```
$ join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

If you want to double up the digits, pipe to sed:

```
$ join file1 file2 | sed -nE 's/^([^[:space:]]*)/\1 \1/p'
001 001 word1 word3
002 002 word2 word4
00n 00n wordn1 wordn2
```

Or specify the `join` output list:

```
$ join -o 1.1,2.1,1.2,2.2 file1 file2
001 001 word1 word3
002 002 word2 word4
00n 00n wordn1 wordn2
```

Comment: [HERE](https://shapeshed.com/unix-join/) is a `join` tutorial.

Comment: My standard operation procedure regarding linux commands is: when it doubt hit it with `man`, in this case `man join`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { map[$1]=$2;next } map[$1] { print $1" "$1" "map[$1]" "$2 } ' file1 file2
```

Process the first file (NR==FNR) and create an array (map) with the first space delimited field as the index and the second field the value. Then for the second file, check if there is an entry in map and if there is, print the first field twice along with the value in map for the index and the second field.